# Using ids from two columns to list data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple friends system built in CakePHP with two tables: Users and Friends

```
Users
id,
username,
password

Friends
id
user_id
friend_id
status
```

To list the friends for a user I do the following:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array( 'conditions' => array('User.username' => $username)));

// First get a list of friend ids
$friendsList = $this->Friend->find('list', 
    array(
        'conditions'=>array(
           'Friend.user_id'=>$user['User']['id'],
           'Friend.status'=>1
        ),
        'fields'=>array(
            'Friend.friend_id'
        )
    )
);

// Then list users with matching ids
$friends = $this->User->find('all', 
    array(
        'conditions'=>array(
           'User.id'=>$friendsList
        ),
    )
);
```

Now this works fine for listing friends that the user has friended as it's pulling the list of friend ids that the user id matches in the friends table. The problem is if a friend has friended the user then the ids will be reversed in the columns and therefore it wont show the friendship when viewing one user but will the other... If that makes sense?

How do I fix this? I basically need to find all matching ids in both columns for the user and then pull out the friend id or user id that matches the row.

I've posted the models as well (although I don't think they really matter for this question as the issue is with the query rather than the relationships which are working).

User Model:

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User'=>array(
            'className'              => 'User',
            'joinTable'              => 'friends',
            'with'                   => 'Friend',
            'foreignKey'             => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'friend_id'
        )
 );
```

Friend model is virtualised!

Thanks

**EDIT: Doing this fixes the problem:**

```
// First get a list of friend ids
$friendsList1 = $this->Friend->find('list', 
    array(
        'conditions'=>array(
           'Friend.user_id'=>$user['User']['id'],
           'Friend.status'=>1
        ),
        'fields'=>array(
            'Friend.friend_id'
        )
    )
);

$friendsList2 = $this->Friend->find('list', 
    array(
        'conditions'=>array(
           'Friend.friend_id'=>$user['User']['id'],
           'Friend.status'=>1
        ),
        'fields'=>array(
            'Friend.user_id'
        )
    )
);

$friendsList = array_merge($friendsList1,$friendsList2);

// Then list users with matching ids
$friends = $this->User->find('all', 
    array(
        'conditions'=>array(
           'User.id'=>$friendsList
        ),
    )
);
```

But the performance could be rather poor if I have a large DB of users I presume.

Comment: You are querying the same model twice. You should be able to merge these in your conditions array with OR.

Comment: Could you show an example of that? As it seems more complex to me than a simple OR because I'm returning a different field for each find statement. Thanks

Comment: Just returns an empty array then?

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to put the statements in an array... Try it now

Comment: Nope still not working. The error sql is: ` SELECT `Friend`.`id` FROM `db`.`friends` AS `Friend` WHERE `Friend`.`status` = 1 AND ((`Friend`.`friend_id` = 6) OR (`Friend`.`user_id` = 6)) AND fields IN ('Friend.user_id', 'Friend.friend_id')`

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Where is that trailing `AND` coming from? `(Friend.user_id = 6)) AND ` remove your `fields' from the query

Comment: I'm not sure. Cake does tend to do a lot of automagic with queries. Removing the fields from the statement doesn't work either. It just returns an array of the row ids.

Comment: Something else is going on because the code is identical to this http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#complex-find-conditions. Scroll down to the section that starts with this : `Cake accepts all valid SQL boolean operations, including AND, OR, NOT, XOR` We may need to see the exact statement you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this to be a recursive table so that the model works correctly. 
You essentially want User to habtm User. So your model should look more like this.

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User'=>array(
            'className'              => 'User',
            'joinTable'              => 'users_user',
            'foreignKey'             => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'friend_id',
            'fields'                 => array('id','user_id','friend_id'),
        )
 );
```

Then you can query the User model and get all the relations as they should be. like so:

```
$friends = ($this->User->Friend->find('all', array('conditions'=>array(
    'Friend.id'=>$loggedinuserid,
                    "OR" => array (
                     "User.id" => $loggedinuserid,
                    ) 
))));
```

Or if your original model works:

```
$friendsList = $this->Friend->find('list', 
    array(
        'conditions'=>array(
           'Friend.status'=>1,
           "OR"=>array(
                 array('Friend.friend_id'=>$user['User']['id']),
                 array('Friend.user_id'=>$user['User']['id'])
                )
        ),
        'fields'=>array(
            'Friend.user_id'
            'Friend.friend_id'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I'd still have the same issue though. As when I do the query I need to match on both user_id and friend_id when doing the initial list which isn't related to the model.

Comment: Nope none of that is working. It's just pulling out 1 friend now. Perhaps I could use the array merge on my original code?

Comment: I tried it exactly as you posted but it just didn't like it. In my OP I have posted what I have tried based on your older answer but mixed with my code and that seems to work fine. A bit dirty but it does work. Although I'm guessing it will be poorer performance.